# Hasse diagram with respect to the partial order $\subseteq$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, lattice-orders

I have an exercise which states to draw a Hasse Diagram of the following

$\{X \subseteq \{1,2,3,4\} | 2 \in X \ \lor 3 \notin X \}$  with respect to the partial order $\subseteq$

[My Work]:- I have the Hasse diagram for it in the picture below.

My doubt is

(1) Should $\{1,3,4\}$ be also in the diagram

(2) Is $\{1,4\}$ a valid subset?

[image]

Comment: $X=\{1,3,4\}$ shouldn't be there because it doesn't satisfy the condition $2\in X\vee 3\not\in X$. Similarly $\{1,4\}$ is fine. I'm not really sure where your confusion arises.

Comment: Ok, so you mean that the every subset which satisfies either  $\{2\}$ or $\{1,2,4\}$ is a valid subset.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "satisfies" $\{2\}$. You can't satisfy a set. What *is* true is that every set $X$ where either $2$ is in $X$ or $3$ is not is a valid subset.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. Will frame the answer accordingly.